# CRON Example for Strapi

Tags: cron, content-management-system, strapi

Hi I was wondering If anyone got examples of using Cron Schedule functions on Strapi: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/configurations/configurations.html#functions
like sending email, accessing the strapi config, etc.

Comment: The example in the documentation is not enough ?
What are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
'*/1 * * * *': async() => {
    console.log("I am running " + new Date(), Object.keys(strapi.config));
    await strapi.services.article.publish();
  }
```

In **your-project/config/functions/cron.js**. you can add as many functions in the above format. 
The function name in itself is a cron expression which is parsed by strapi to execute at frequent intervals. There are many online tools that will tell you the cron expression that you want to create.

The above function runs every 1 minute, by which I am publishing a content type by using strapi.services. i.e. in file your-project/api/article/services/Article.js
I have written a service layer method that at the moment is publishing an article.

Similarly, you can send an email from your email content type or any utility file that you have made to trigger an email.
For accessing strapi config use: **strapi.config** object instead of **strapi.services**

Answer (score 11):

Some example of CRON jobs for Strapi

add this line server.js

```
...
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  cron :{
    enabled: true
  },
  admin:
...
```

cron.js some examples

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Simple examples.
   */
  '*/5 * * * * *': () => {
    console.log(" ~ file: cron.js ~ executing action ~Every 5sec");
  },  
  '*/10 * * * * *': () => {
    console.log(" ~ file: cron.js ~ executing action ~Every 10sec");
  },
  '* */5 * * * *': () => {
    console.log(" ~ file: cron.js ~ executing action ~Every 5min");
  },
  '* * */5 * * *': () => {
    console.log(" ~ file: cron.js ~ executing action ~Every 5hour");
  },   
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Strapi 3 has cron jobs turned off by default. Make sure you turn them on first :)

You also don't need to do */1 for every minute in a cron job, just *, as * means every, and it only checks once a minute.

[image: cron jobs must be turned on]

Comment: I believe this is not available via UI anymore and you have to do it through `server.json`

Comment: We must do in server.js:  cron: {  enabled: true  }

Answer (score 2):

My requirement was to fetch data from an external MSSQL DB (master data) hosted under RDS (AWS) and update the strapi product catolog (mongodb) every minute.

I've created a custom "cron" folder under "root" to keep all my custom modules in order keep a clean "cron.js".

Under "cron.js" i've simply imported my custom module to call the external module:

```
const fwSync = require('../../cron/dataSync');
```

[image: Import your custom module e.g 'dataSync' where all your business logic is located. Note: I've passed 'strapi' to my module from cron.]

[image: On my custom module i'm using sequelize to connect to MSSQL. Once data is fetched i'm able to use strapi.query directly.]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call multiple cron jobs

```
import firstCronJob from '../src/plugins/first-cron-job';
import secondCronJob from '../src/plugins/second-cron-job';

export default ({ env }) => ({
    host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
    app: {
        keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
    },
    cron: {
        enabled: true,
        tasks: {
            ...firstCronJob,
            ...secondCronJob,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).